# Grails Pagination: how to use pagination to restrict the number of rows

Tags: grails

I have a query which gives a result of about 100 rows. Here is the code for the controllers

```
def bandsOneTrack = {
    def bands = Band.executeQuery("Select b from Band as b where size(b.tracks) > (select count(t.id) from Band as ba join ba.tracks as t where ba.id = b.id and t.ourContract is not null) and (select count(t.id) from Band as ba join ba.tracks as t where ba.id = b.id and t.ourContract is not null) >= 1" )
    render(view: 'bands_list' , model: [ bands : bands ])
}
```

It gives me the result set of about 100 rows but they are appearing inside a same page. 
Now I want to use pagination so that I can restrict it to only 20 rows per page.
What should I do, and also how to use pagination for this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On your pagination tag check the total parameter. That should be the total number of records. In your case 100 so that the pagination tag can calculate the total number of pages.

Something like this [here](http://grails.org/doc/2.0.x/ref/Tags/paginate.html):

```
<g:paginate controller="Book" action="list" total="${bookInstanceTotal}" />
```

You might need to execute your query once to find the total number of records.

```
def list() {
    params.max = Math.min(params.max ? params.int('max') : 10, 100)
    def ls = Book.executeQuery("from Book a",[max: params.max, offset: params.offset])
    def totalCount = Book.executeQuery("from Book a").size()
    [bookInstanceList: ls, bookInstanceTotal: totalCount]
}
```

Comment: Alidad can you please tell me, that the way we have set the params.max, how can we set the default value of params.offset.

Comment: You can pass offset default through the pagination tag. <g:paginate ... offset ="20"/> but if you set this offset, you need to tell your action to start from that offset the first time the page is loaded as well. something like this def ls = Book.executeQuery("from Book a",[max: params.max, offset: params.offset?:20])

Comment: Most people forget that totalCount is the sum total of all books and not size of books returned in the first query. You're a life saver.

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly, you add max and offset properties to the model you're passing to your view, it should automatically wire in pagination.  At that point, you should be able to use the paginate tag to iterate through your result sets.  See the docs here:

http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Tags/paginate.html

Comment: I have use max:25 but this will restrict the records 25 per page but it doesn't show the rest of the records.

Answer (score 0):

**Grails Criteria Query and pagination params**

```
params.max = params?.max as Integer ?: 10
params.offset = params?.offset as Integer ?: 0
params.sort = params?.sort ?: "email"
params.order = params?.order ?: "asc"
params.filter = params?.filter ?: ""
params.packet = params?.packet ?: ""

def members = Member.createCriteria().list(params)
  {
    or
    {
      if(params.filter != ""){
        ilike("firstName", "%" + params.filter + "%")
        ilike("lastName", "%" + params.filter + "%")
        ilike("email", "%" + params.filter + "%")
        try {
          params.filter as Long
          eq("citizenId" , params.filter.toLong())
        }catch (e) {

        }
        ilike("mobile", "%" + params.filter + "%")
      }
    }
  }

def dataMembers = [:]
dataMembers.data = members
dataMembers.totalRecord = members.totalCount
render dataMembers as JSON
```

**Output**

```
{
"data": [
    {
      "id":1,
      "firstName":name
    },
    {
      "id":2,
      "firstName":name
    }
  ],
"totalRecord":5
}
```